# Convert 4 one-to-one mapped lists into a list of dicts (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I have 4 lists where the elements are one-to-one mapped. There are *tens of thousands of elements*. I want to create one dict giving the 4 properties for each element, and then I want to put these dicts into a list. (My end goal is to create a pandas DataFrame and save it as an HDF5 file.)

Is there an easy memory-efficient way to do this, perhaps using zip() and dict() instead of a for loop?

As a working example for Python, please consider:

```
list1 = ['obj1','obj2','obj3']
list2 = ['cat','dog','tree']
list3 = [7,8,9]
list4 = ['red','green','blue']
```

So the idea is that in the end I want a *list of dicts* that looks like

```
[{'obj':'obj1','type':'cat','num':7,'color':'red'}, 
 {'obj':'obj2','type':'dog','num':8,'color':'green'}, 
 {'obj':'obj3','type':'tree','num':9,'color':'blue'}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you tag `pandas` , By using `to_dict`

```
pd.DataFrame({'obj':list1,'type':list2,'num':list3,'color':list4}).to_dict('r')
Out[1204]: 
[{'color': 'red', 'num': 7, 'obj': 'obj1', 'type': 'cat'},
 {'color': 'green', 'num': 8, 'obj': 'obj2', 'type': 'dog'},
 {'color': 'blue', 'num': 9, 'obj': 'obj3', 'type': 'tree'}]
```

Comment: df *is* an end goal according to question :)

Comment: @quantumflash yw~ happy coding

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-pandas option:

```
data = zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)
keys = ['obj', 'type', 'num', 'color']
list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in data]
```

Comment: I should really work on my copy and paste skill, and actually copy the intended line.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a list a `dict` of `dict`s

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
list1 = ['obj1','obj2','obj3']
list2 = ['cat','dog','tree']
list3 = [7,8,9]
list4 = ['red','green','blue']
pd.DataFrame(np.array([list1, list2, list3, list4])).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is using corresponding element from each list (*first dictionary of the output list is with first element from each  input list*) and assuming all list are of same size, using `list comprehension` may be one other way:

```
[{'obj':list1[i], 'type':list2[i], 
  'num':list3[i], 'color':list4[i]} for i in range(len(list1))]
```